# Search for a value in a nested array and then find all parents and expand nodes until the matched value

Tags: typescript

I am able to search the nested array but I am not able to get full path until the match is found. I want to open each folder until the match is found. So instead of traversing forward I need to traverse backwards based on parent id and set a flag to open parent folders.

```
searchArray(subTerms: Tree[], searchTerm: string) {
  subTerms.forEach((term: Tree) => {
     if (term?.displayText.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
       // term matches
     }
     // continue recursion if there are more children to search for all terms
     if (term?.children?.length > 0) {
       this.searchArray(term.children, searchTerm);
     }
  });
}
```

My data looks like this:

```
[{
  "createTime": 1684347344310,
  "qualifiedName": "Test Account Number@dx Taxonomy Test",
  "name": "Test Account Number",
  "updateTime": 1684347344310,
  "guid": "c3991b4c-5202-481f-9a91-ed5f1962c451",
  "status": "Draft",
  "parentTerm": null,
  "displayText": "Test Account Number",
  "templateName": null,
  "shortDescription": null,
  "longDescription": "test account number",
  "children": []
}, {
  "createTime": 1683825963175,
  "qualifiedName": "TestTermWExtendedInfo@dx Taxonomy Test",
  "name": "TestTermWExtendedInfo",
  "updateTime": 1683825963175,
  "guid": "fc94963e-2ad0-4937-8cb7-7dca5024674f",
  "parentTerm": null,
  "displayText": "TestTermWExtendedInfo",
  "templateName": [
    "dxAdditionalTermAttributes"
  ],
  "shortDescription": null,
  "longDescription": "This is a definition",
  "children": [
    {
      "createTime": 1684246871724,
      "qualifiedName": "TestTermWExtendedInfo_Test Term 1@dx Taxonomy Test",
      "name": "TestTermWExtendedInfo_Test Term 1",
      "updateTime": 1684246871724,
      "guid": "e520f5cb-e5b9-4913-bff0-be9493521718",
      "status": "Draft",
      "parentTerm": {
        "termGuid": "fc94963e-2ad0-4937-8cb7-7dca5024674f"
      },
      "displayText": "Test Term 1",
      "templateName": null,
      "shortDescription": null,
      "longDescription": "test",
      "children": [
        {
          "createTime": 1684251862709,
          "qualifiedName": "TestTermWExtendedInfo_Test Term 1_Test_Term_2@dx Taxonomy Test",
          "name": "TestTermWExtendedInfo_Test Term 1_Test_Term_2",
          "updateTime": 1684251862709,
          "guid": "921d93da-cc86-4f87-8c36-96554f8df866",
          "status": "Draft",
          "parentTerm": {
            "termGuid": "e520f5cb-e5b9-4913-bff0-be9493521718"
          },
          "displayText": "Test_Term_2",
          "templateName": null,
          "shortDescription": null,
          "longDescription": null,
          "children": [
            {
              "createTime": 1684333610972,
              "qualifiedName": "TestTermWExtendedInfo_Test Term 1_Test_Term_2_Test Term 3@dx Taxonomy Test",
              "name": "TestTermWExtendedInfo_Test Term 1_Test_Term_2_Test Term 3",
              "updateTime": 1684333610972,
              "guid": "9f128678-c36f-42b5-8bf8-fb5e7557366e",
              "status": "Draft",
              "parentTerm": {
                "termGuid": "921d93da-cc86-4f87-8c36-96554f8df866"
              },
              "displayText": "Test Term Data",
              "templateName": null,
              "shortDescription": null,
              "longDescription": "test 3",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

The key is

```
"parentTerm": {
  "termGuid": "921d93da-cc86-4f87-8c36-96554f8df866"
},
```

When I do a search for "data", I want to expand the tree like below. There could be multiple matches.

[image]

Comment: `showedChildren = children.filter(e=>e.showed); term.showed = showedChildren.length > 0;`